# sudo rpi-update freezes, help

Tags: rpi-update

I am in the process of a `sudo rpi-update`, but it appears to have frozen at  `*** Updating kernel modules`

This is the output from the ssh screen since the update command:

```
sudo rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7938  100  7938    0     0  20235      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25856
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Downloading specific firmware revision (this will take a few minutes)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   168    0   168    0     0    273      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   385
100 43.3M  100 43.3M    0     0   279k      0  0:02:38  0:02:38 --:--:--  444k
 *** Updating firmware
 *** Updating kernel modules
```

1) has it frozen, or just taking a long time?
2) how long shall i leave it like this?
3) Would it brick my PI if i pulled the power?

Please advise this worried novice.

Comment: I would not advise pulling the pug in can take a while to complete the process. I would give it at least an hour. If you pull the plug you are likely be unable to restart your pi, and have to reimage the SD Card.

Comment: I'm running it headless via ssh, could it have lost connection with ssh, but still be going through its update process? It's been going for more than an hour, is there any merit in leaving it overnight?

Comment: I'm running motion webcam software on this PI and can see the live stream, but I cannot SSH into it from my phone's wifi connection. I ran the update via my laptop and putty. Does this suggest that my laptop's ssh has become unresponsive? Can I SSH into it from 2 places at once?

Comment: Yes, it probably means that it is a problem with SSH. Trying another machine or SSH Session may work. If it does you should do a sudo reboot. if that doesn't work I would find a keyboard and try it from the pi itself (you may need to access a virtual terminal). It could also be the WiFi that is down.

Comment: It normally lets me ssh in from my phone, but that isn't working. I can control the webcam via it's own interface, so does this mean the firmware updated for sure? Would it have done an automatic reboot? I can't connect a monitor without removing the power first, and have tried to ssh in from winscp, and another putty session on the same laptop, but no joy. if the pi is still working, then I have a script that will reboot the pi after loosing the wifi signal, should I turn my router off and let it reboot?

Comment: It may have done a reboot,but I can't say for sure. I don't know that you have another option than to pull the power at this point (and hope).

Comment: I'm only confidant to do this if me seeing the live stream definitely means the update finished.

Comment: There is really no way to be sure,but it seems likely and the reason it appeared frozen was that the network or SSH was down.

Comment: You may want to remember this and avoid doing updates remotely. You may want to either delete or answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled the power, connected it to a keyboard and tv, then did a 'shutdown -rF now' and 'rpi-update' and now have it connecting via ssh